# UI swipe displaying one map instead of two maps for left and right side

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

https://code.earthengine.google.com/ccd6f6b1fcac3203f1e79c81f5a09c84

So for this I have everything working other than the fact that only one side of the map (left/right) will display one year while the other side displays the same year even though I filtered it out to display a different year. So my split map is not working correctly.

```
//Crops in the US by year.
var getCrops = function(year) {
  // Import the CDL  collection.
  var dataset = ee.ImageCollection('USDA/NASS/CDL')
    
  // Filter the collection by year.
  var crops = dataset.filter(ee.Filter.eq('system:index', year)).first();
  
  // Select the land cover band.
  var landcover = crops.select('cropland');
  return ui.Map.Layer(landcover, {}, year);
  
};

// Create a dictionary with each year as the key 
// and its corresponding image layer as the value.
var images = {
  '2013': getCrops('2013'),
  '2014': getCrops('2013'),
  '2015': getCrops('2013'),
  '2016': getCrops('2013'),
  '2017': getCrops('2013'),
}
  
/*
* Set up the maps and control widgets
*/

// Create the left map, and have it display the first layer.
var leftMap = ui.Map();
leftMap.setControlVisibility(false);
var leftSelector = addLayerSelector(leftMap, 0, 'top-left');

// Create the right map, and have it display the last layer.
var rightMap = ui.Map();
rightMap.setControlVisibility(true);
var rightSelector = addLayerSelector(rightMap, 6, 'top-right');

// Adds a layer selection widget to the given map, to allow users to 
// change which image is displayed in the associated map.
function addLayerSelector(mapToChange, defaultValue, position) {
  var label = ui.Label('Select a year:');

  // This function changes the given map to show the selected image.
  function updateMap(selection) {
    //mapToChange.layers().set(0, ui.Map.Layer(images[selection]));
    mapToChange.layers().set(0, images[selection]);
  }

  // Configure a selection dropdown to allow the user to choose
  // between images, and set the map to update when a user 
  // makes a selection.
  var select = ui.Select({items: Object.keys(images), onChange: updateMap});
  //select.setValue(Object.keys(images)[defaultValue], true);

  var controlPanel =
      ui.Panel({widgets: [label, select], style: {position: position}});

  mapToChange.add(controlPanel);
}


// Set the legend title.
var title = 'Crop Land Cover Classification';

// Set the legend position.
var position = 'bottom-right';

// Define a dictionary that will be used to make a legend
var dict = {
  "names": [
    "Corn",
    "Cotton",
    "Rice",
    "Sorghum",
    "Soybeans",
    "Sunflower",
    "Peanuts",
    "Tobacco",
    "Sweet Corn",
    "Pop or Orn Corn",
    "Mint",
    "Barley",
    "Other Small Grains",
    "Other Crops",
    "Misc Vegs & Fruits",
  ],
  
  "colors": [ 
    '#ffd300', '#ff2626', '#00a8e2', '#ff9e0a', '#267000', '#ffff00',   
    '#70a500', '#00af49', '#dda50a' , '#dda50a', '#7cd3ff', '#e2007c',
    '#d69ebc','#00af49',    '#ff6666'
    ]
};


// Create a panel to hold the legend widget.
var legend = ui.Panel({
  style: {
    position: position,
    padding: '8px 15px'
  }
});

// Function to generate the legend.
function addCategoricalLegend(panel, dict, title) {
  
  // Create and add the legend title.
  var legendTitle = ui.Label({
    value: title,
    style: {
      fontWeight: 'bold',
      fontSize: '18px',
      margin: '0 0 4px 0',
      padding: '0'
    }
  });
  panel.add(legendTitle);
  
  var loading = ui.Label('Loading legend...', {margin: '2px 0 4px 0'});
  panel.add(loading);
  
  // Creates and styles 1 row of the legend.
  var makeRow = function(color, name) {
    // Create the label that is actually the colored box.
    var colorBox = ui.Label({
      style: {
        backgroundColor: color,
        // Use padding to give the box height and width.
        padding: '8px',
        margin: '0 0 4px 0'
      }
    });
  
    // Create the label filled with the description text.
    var description = ui.Label({
      value: name,
      style: {margin: '0 0 4px 6px'}
    });
  
    return ui.Panel({
      widgets: [colorBox, description],
      layout: ui.Panel.Layout.Flow('horizontal')
    });
  };
  
  // Get the list of palette colors and class names from the image.
  var palette = dict.colors;
  var names = dict.names;
  loading.style().set('shown', false);
  
  for (var i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
    panel.add(makeRow(palette[i], names[i]));
  }
  
  rightMap.add(panel);
  
}

addCategoricalLegend(legend, dict, title);


// Create a SplitPanel to hold the adjacent, linked maps.
var splitPanel = ui.SplitPanel({
  firstPanel: leftMap,
  secondPanel: rightMap,
  wipe: true,
  style: {stretch: 'both'}
});

// Set the SplitPanel as the only thing in the UI root.
ui.root.widgets().reset([splitPanel]);
var linker = ui.Map.Linker([leftMap, rightMap]);
leftMap.setCenter(-100, 40, 4);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues I spot. First, you probably don't want the crops for 2013 no matter which years you select?

```
var images = {
  '2013': getCrops('2013'),
  '2014': getCrops('2013'),
  '2015': getCrops('2013'),
  '2016': getCrops('2013'),
  '2017': getCrops('2013'),
}
```

Secondly, `getCrops()` returns an `ee.Map.Layer`. These layers are created up-front and get reused. You end up in trouble when selecting the same year on both maps, as the layer cannot be rendered on two maps at the same time.

I would drop `images` altogether, and generate the layer on the fly when selecting a year.

```
var years = ['2013', '2014', '2015', '2016', '2017']
...

function addLayerSelector(mapToChange, defaultValue, position) {
  var label = ui.Label('Select a year:')

  function updateMap(selection) {
    mapToChange.layers().set(0, getCrops(selection))
  }

  var select = ui.Select({items: years, onChange: updateMap})
  ...
}
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/e9a5427c04f0d2ea0b6534b14cb2fb9a

Comment: Thank you so much! Also would you be able to help me on this code link as well then? It has the same issue where the swipe doesnt work properly as well as the palette not working correctly as well. I tried doing what you did for this code on the new one yet it did not work the same.
New Code Link: https://code.earthengine.google.com/dfbc5119133ff75b7691b5832a73c0f0

Comment: My apologies this is the new code link if assistance is possible: https://code.earthengine.google.com/7cfa01d28da4d629a3aec7e598eb4682